Needed available fields Wazuh Dashboard/Discover don't exist
I have a problem with the fact that the CPU and RAM usage fields of the agent are not displayed in the Discover section. I have read the documentation on creating a dashboard based on these fields, but I do not have them. I have installed wazuh-manager for Quickstart documentation. I did not change the ossec.conf file on the agent.
Agent - Windows 10
Server - Ubuntu 16.04
What am I doing wrong?
Documentation dashboard
My visualize
